# SSRS R2 Chart report download to pdf slow

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, pdf-generation

We have an issue with downloading the report to pdf. server: SSRS R2 as mentioned.

Report is specific to one ID. so chart will be displayed for one single ID. I used subreport method to send multiple ID's to the report and get different pages of chart in one single report. When i send about 38 ID's(38 pages of report) it takes about 2 mins to download to PDF and the ratio is proportionate ( the max we send was about 90 ID's which was taking about 5mins, not acceptable from users point of view).
Report was able to render in split seconds time. So, we have no issues from sql DB. We have thoroughly enhanced sql to optimum performance. 
Reportviewer was able to show the report in split seconds time. But, **the issue is very specific to downloading that report to pdf**. Even excel download is very fast and downloads in few seconds.

I have gone through lots of search on google and tried lots of stuff like disabling the antivirus on server, removed all the global parameters from child report as well as main report and also tried to keep caching enabled. 
Finally, we have large memory, multi cored CPU on the server and enough disk space. As, pdf download from ssrs is CPU intensive and excel is RAM intensive, we have looked into it.

Thanks in advance for your replies. This is my first post on stack overflow. This site has been a savior lot of times to me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ram Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect one of two things. Either it is the fact that you are trying to render so many subreports and for some reason this slows down the PDF renderer. Try disabling some of the subreports or limit it to rendering it only once (if they are in some kind of repeating object). Either that or remake the report so that it doesn't need to call the subreports.

The other possibility is that the charts are very large or complex. I've heard stories of the PDF renderer taking a very long time to generate charts that are large in size, and making them smaller has improved the performance. I'm not sure how you should handle that if this is the case. That'll depend on your situation.

I would try disabling bits of the report and seeing how it affects the rendering time in order to figure out what exactly is the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we have already considered the path of moving away with subreports and consolidate into one report, but was unsuccessful because of the way report is customized.

To be more precise, The charts are really not large and complex. they are very simple charts but still we will try your suggestion of disabling few features inside the report.